# How to detect the state of a network interface whether it is enabled?

Tags: c#, network-programming

How to detect if a network interface is enabled/disabled?

```
public Boolean IsNicEnabled(String nic) {  return true; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class about this.

Querying interface status can be done using the [`NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getisnetworkavailable%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method call.

Example:

```
var adapters = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
if (adapters != null && adapters.Length > 0)
{
    foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in adapters) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Network interface {0} is {1}", 
                      adapter.Name,
                      (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()?"up":"down")
                      );
    }
}
```

The above code will yield results as:

> Network interface *Local Area Network* is *up*
>
> Network interface *Loopback Pseudo-Interface* 1 is *up*

Now you can encapsulate this into your property's getter for instance you just need to add filtering for the adapters name.

Comment: But how does the static method NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() know the state of the adapter instance?